# How can I get pydantic to generate Enum descriptions in a json schema?

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, pydantic

I am trying to generate a JSON schema from a Pydantic model which contains several options, each with its own description. The goal is to show the options and the descriptions for a developer working with these schemas in an IDE.

Is there a way to have the `Model.schema_json()` call to output something like this:

```
{
    "BackgroundColorType": {
        "oneOf": [
        {
            "const": "Active",
            "description": "This will show a color for an active state"
        },
        ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Containing descriptions for each option?

I tried everything but there doesn't seem to be possible to add descriptions to Python's Enums.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you show here is a bit contradictory because the `anyOf` key represents a **union** in the JSON Schema, it does not represent enums. There is a separate [`enum`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#id4) keyword for that. Please _Edit_ your post and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some actual Python code and show what you think should happen.